# How to run an SSIS package upon Project deployment?

Tags: deployment, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have an SSIS Project made up of several packages. The "main" package executes the others, and it runs nonstop.

Everytime changes are applied to one or more packages, I need to run the project deployment wizard in VS, then stop the ongoing Active Operation in SQL Server (2016) and then run the package again (also via SQL Server). This can happen several times a day, so it's becoming a nuisance.

Is there a way to trigger a "package-stop; package-start" routine on Deployment?

Comment: I'm almost scared to ask, but why do you need an SSIS package that runs "nonstop"?

Comment: Whenever I receive a type of data, its respective package is set to apply queries to that data. Otherwise, if no data is found, the main package "goes to sleep" for a while. Rinse and repeat. (I hope my answer clarified the purpose of this project)

Comment: Why not create a SQL Agent Job to run on a recurring schedule? You can configure it to run every X minutes, where X is how long it would normally "go to sleep" for. Then you don't need to manually stop and restart after deploy.

Comment: The main package sleeps for 60 seconds. Do you think it is acceptable to schedule a job to execute the main package every minute? I was afraid this could somehow overcharge the SQL Server.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather have a job that is scheduled to run every 60 seconds than a package that runs non-stop.

Comment: I followed your advice. Thanks a bunch!